# Error HTTP/1.0 405 Method not Allowed

Tags: android, http-status-code-405

I want to make an Htttp Connection Here is my code

```
try
{
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpMethod = new HttpPost("http://www.google.co.in/");
String requestBody = "some text";
HttpMethod.setEntity(new StringEntity(requestBody));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpMethod);
textView.setText(response.getStatusLine().toString());
}
```

But i m unable to and get the "HTTP/1.0 405 Method not Allowed" error
I will be thankfull your help

Answer (score 19):

It means that the requested URL does not accept the POST method. Try again with GET.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you should try with a server that accepts POST requests. There's probably nothing wrong with your code, Google's front page just doesn't do POST.

One quick example of a server you could use I can think of is [JSFiddle's echo feature](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html). I'm sure they won't mind.

Comment: Yep, use the `HttpGet` class and use the `setParams` method.