# Sending http requests to server from background service fails

Tags: android, httprequest

I'm sending HTTP requests to server from working in background Service in Android. He works fine just when device is connected to computer through USB cable. If device isn't connected to computer - service still sends requests, but they didn't come to server. If i plug device to computer again - all sended requests coming immediately to server.

I'm using AsyncTask for sending requests.

Web service working good, I'm tested it with hurl.it
I can't understand what's the reason.

**Edited:**
I'm sending requests with ->

```
        URL url = null;
    URLConnection connection = null;

    InputStream inputStream = null;

    String strURL = String.format("%s/%s", serviceURL, params);
    try{
    url = new URL(strURL);
    connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.connect();

    inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
    }catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Working solution**
I was really shoked, when i found, that requests to server should be called not just from background thread, but with call-back construction, which provides interfaces.

In my service I'm starting AsyncTask

```
MyTask task = new MyTask(); 
task.execute((Void)null);
```

and implementing interface AsyncTaskHost in service class

```
...
@Override
public void onTaskStart(){
    // sending http request to server using method from above
}
@Override
public void onTaskFinish(){
    // doing additional work here, after getting response from request
}
```

my Interface:

```
public interface AsyncTaskHost{
    public void onTaskStart();
    public void onTaskFinish();
}
```

my async task class:

```
public class UploadCoordinates extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
private AsyncTaskHost taskHost;
private Context context;

public UploadCoordinates(Context context, AsyncTaskHost taskHost) {
    this.taskHost = taskHost;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    taskHost.onTaskStart();

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void param) {
    if (isCancelled()) {
        return;
    }

    taskHost.onUploadFinish();
}
}
```

Now all works fine. without interface, async task doesn't want to work without usb cable. i don't know, this is magic for me (or Android OS blocking all requests, ports or something like that).

Comment: Can u put your code and the Errors that occurs when not connected to computer..!!

Comment: no errors received - doesn't matter connected to computer or not. looks like I can't send http request without connecting to computer, is blocked port or what, i don't know.

Answer (score 0):

See if this could help:

```
URL url = null;
InputStream inputStream = null;

String strURL = String.format("%s/%s", serviceURL, params);
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpclient.getParams(), 10000);

 try{
    url = new URL(strURL);
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
  }catch(IOException ioe){
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: @VeaceslavGaidarji-Sorry about that !!

Comment: if i use httpclient example like u posted, he receives me reponse code 405 "Method not allowed". but BufferedInputStream still works fine and sends request to server (just with plugged USB cable :()

Comment: Refer this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904842/error-http-1-0-405-method-not-allowed

Comment: yeah, I'm tried with Http "GET" method also, he also works fine with plugged USB cable. and now I'm tried to send request not from background service, but from main activity. and still doesn't work without USB cable.

Comment: @VeaceslavGaidarji-Then something is wrong outside the JAVA class...may be in manifest file..

Comment: Does anything else connect without the USB cable?  The browser?

Answer (score 0):

depending on what you would like to do you could also try out jsoup from jsoup.org

Judging by that it only works when your usb cable is connected is a bit strange. Try deactivating you internet on your computer and enable it only on your phone. It might be that some general internet sharing settings are interfering.

Comment: yeah, and I thought so. but found solution in other place. see edited post ;)

Answer (score 0):

I know it'a a bit old post i am answering because i faced same issue it digested my 2-3 hours to solve. Problem is when sending request via emulator to "Local" server and if you write

```
http://localhost:8080/yourapp/yourServelt
```

it will not send request to server. You must have to mention the IP address of your machine i.e

```
http://10.0.0.15:8080/yourapp/yourServlet
```